# How to manage site files in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to replace dreamweaver as coding tool - by notepad++.
Download the last version, and cannot find option do display folders (root folder for example) which my files belongs to.
Is there any explorer-like window and if not - must I go to windows explorer each time if I need to open or manage the files ?
I also need to see and open related files (i.e. linked to an opened file) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe NP++ has some plugin for Explorer window. You may try also SynWrite editor instead of NP++ -- it has Explorer window (left panel), project management etc.

Comment: NP++ has "Explorer" plugin. It's avail through Plugin Manager in NP++.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved. And it seems npp is much better then DW in just coding.